# SharePoint SQL server volume shadow copy service is utilizing more disk space

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server-2012

we are supporting SharePoint 2013 on premises servers ans using SQL server log shipping configuration for Disaster recovery.

We observed that Windows Volume Shadow copy service is enabled in SQL server and it is utilizing high amount of sql server disk space, where we are storing content database .mdf and .ldf file.

Is this volume shadow copy service really needed to be enabled and run in SQL server for SharePoint farm?

We configured logshipping on primary SQL server and managing the content backup to DR SQL servers successfully.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Volume shadow copy service is needed to be enabled and run in SQL server for SharePoint farm.

Refer to the following article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee923636(v=ws.10)

Comment: is Volume shadow copy service mandatory to run in SQL server for SharePoint farm? The problem is, it is consuming lot of disk space in SQL server  where the content database data files are stored.

Comment: We are using SQL log shipping configuration for database backups to DR servers and not using any volume shadow copy services from OS level.